# Can I create a preset of options for the LoL spectator mode?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm a referee in a local LoL league, and something that irks me is that at the beginning of every game I have to press I and then check scoreboard to get the scoreboard.

I'd like it to be checked right away when I load in the game I'm spectating. Is there a way to do that?

Seeing as the LoL Esports feed never seem to have a game where they forget for a few seconds to activate the scoreboard, it leads me to think that it is an option somewhere that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also deal with organized spectating and unfortunately, there is no simple/built in way to do this. I know that Riot's official spectator that is used on stream has many unlocked features including presets, unlocked zoom range, and replay creators. None of these feature are currently live, however.